# Have tried all other answers found for this problem: Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed [..]

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, google-play

I am trying to upload a completely new app to the play store but am being met with the error "Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again". I have tried my best to follow and understand the instructions and believe I have followed them.

From https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key I have done these steps and created a new keystore.jks file. I then continue to the next step and sign my app with that same key, providing the same password used to create it. I left they key alias as key0 which was the default, and checked off 'Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps in Google Play App Signing', though I have not had a chance to use the file it exports. I made sure the build type was set to release, not debug and made my app-release.aab file.

I then continue onto the next section for 'Opt in to app signing by Google Play'/'[Opt in a new app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll_new)'. Step 1 is covered by the steps I've taken previously. I then sign into the developer account and navigate to the app I set up (there is only one associated with the account), and go to the App Releases page from the navigation on the right.

I scroll down to 'Internal test track' and edit release. It is set to edit not create because initially I tried to upload a React Native 0.57 app and found that I had to update it to a more recent version before the store would accept it. I kept the name and 'what's new in this release?' section but removed the app that was there previously and saved the page. I also made sure to remove this previous version from the Artifact library, which is now empty.

When I try to upload my app-release.aab file I am told "Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1: [...]". This is where I am stuck now.

Things I have researched and tried:

1. I have tried cleaning the project and recreating the keystore file and rebuilding the app with that. Same wrong key result.
2. I have changed the location of the .jks file in case there some caching going on in. Same wrong key result.
3. I have tried removing the debug.keystore file from android/app/debug.keystore, AS did not like that and would not build the bundle successfully without it
4. I have checked for a few debuggable properties that may have been set within the .gradle file(s), debuggable = true, and testCoverageEnabled = true (Or some other value). Neither of these were set.
5. I have made sure that the same password was being used in creation through the above steps to create and sign. Same wrong key result.
6. Crying and giving up. Same wrong key result.
7. I have read that having the signingConfig specified anywhere in your gradle files will override the choice you make during the bundle creation and have commented that out for release buildtypes. After uploading I was told my app was not signed.
8. Instead of using AS, I followed this guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android and made an appname.keystore file, signingConfigs { release {..}} entry for that and creating the .aab through command line via gradlew bundleRelease as instructed, then uploaded that. Same wrong key result.

I am absolutely, completely lost. I have no idea what to do next. Everything I have found and tried has failed, I cannot find any more things to try. Please help me.

Below are my gradle files:

android\app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.[..]"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.+"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.X.+'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

android\build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "26.+"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && (
            !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats') ||
            !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-vision-image-label') ||
            !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-clearcut') ||
            !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-flags') ||
            !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-phenotype')
            )) {
            details.useVersion "12.+"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && (
            details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats') ||
            details.requested.name.contains('play-services-vision-image-label') ||
            details.requested.name.contains('play-services-clearcut') ||
            details.requested.name.contains('play-services-flags') ||
            details.requested.name.contains('play-services-phenotype')
            )) {
            details.useVersion "+"
        }
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.firebase'
        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && details.requested.name.contains('firebase-messaging')) {
            details.useVersion "12.+"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // default: "+"
    firebaseVersion = "+" // default: "+"
    // Other settings
    compileSdkVersion = 28 // default: 23
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3" // default: "23.0.1"
    targetSdkVersion = 28 // default: 23
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=[...].keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=[...]
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=[...]
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it sounds as if you had created and signed a React Native version of your app, with the same bundle identifier, and tried, and/or succeeded to upload the binary to your Google Play console.  Now, you are trying to upload another binary, signed with a different key, but with the same bundle identifier.  Is that correct?

If so, you are going to have to change the App Name and Bundle Identifier to something brand new (unless you have found a way to completely delete all previous references to your project from your console and 'add' instead of 'edit', which I don't think is possible).

Additionally, you should check what date you used as an expiration date for your 'Release' keystore.  Typically, they have a maximum date that they suggest you use, which is something like 100 years in the future, but you'd have to google the exact date they suggest.  If you expire your Release keystore too soon, you won't be able to build Release builds after it expires.

Comment: I believe the expiry date was the default, which is 25 years iirc?

And yes I tried to upload the 0.57 version, it was rejected, I upgraded it to 0.61 and now the store won't accept that. So I need to change it from com.appname to com.appname2 or something? Is that right?

I only got as far as uploading the previous 0.57 app to the internal test track where it was rejected. I didn't realize permanently destroying a valid bundle identifier was so easy, should I be using a com.thisisnotthefinalbundlename until the very end and switch it out just before I publish it?

Comment: I was going to try and remove all references since it's just the app name and release notes in the internal track, but it seems the Google Play Console is inaccessible right now, gives me a "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (1000004)" when I try to access it. As soon as I am able I will try to delete everything I can from the console and add instead of edit.

Comment: OK, you can discard an app release which I did for the internal track. I have no reference to any APKs or anything like that anywhere as far as I know. Nothing in the artifact library, no apks in drafts, nothing. I created a new release under Internal Test, chose my app-release.aab file, and received the same error.

Comment: Well, the first time you upload a build, that build is signed with a keystore key that has a sha1 signature, and that signature can never change.  So, if you used a different key to sign your 0.61 build than your 0.57 build, that would explain it.  They would have different sha1 signatures.  I don't think it is enough to delete all of the binaries.  I think the sha1 signature gets permanently associated with the App Name and/or Bundle Identifier.  So, you would have to change one or both as if you were uploading an entirely new app.

Comment: I deleted the application and started completely fresh and was able to upload it that way. I think I am on my way now, though I am reading it could take 1-2+ weeks before the app is published and I can review it on the internal test track. Do you know if the issues I see in the pre-launch report will stop this process from moving forward?

Comment: Congratulations!  No, they display some dire-looking warnings that are mostly related to optimizing the size of your build, but if your binary is not exceedingly large, you should be fine.  A limited set of 'team members' should be able to download the build from your internal test track immediately.  People who are outside of your 'team' will need to wait 1-2 weeks until reviewed.

Comment: Well I am the team unfortunately :) and from what I'm reading until that opt-in link is displayed under Internal Test Track -> Manage testers I can't download the app through their servers. Do you know how I can bypass that and download the build immediately?

Comment: If you are not seeing the Opt-In link under the Internal test Track -> Manage testers, then you haven't released the build to the internal test track yet.  What does the button say in the upper right corner?  If you have released the build to the internal test track, it should say Release to Alpha (which would promote the release to the Alpha track - don't do that).  If it says Release, then you haven't released it to the internal test track yet, and won't have an Opt-In link.

Comment: I do see the "Release To Alpha" button, and above that (outside the Release 1.0 window container/container I see another "Create Release" button but I think that's for creating a new different release. I just noticed that there's a 'Internal app sharing' section separate from the Internal test section on the general 'Release Management' page. I took a quick peek and it does look like that would let me do what you're describing. I won't get a chance to verify till tomorrow but I'll let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: Yea, that's a new section, and it does look like it might work for you.  But usually, I got an Opt-In link in the above internal manage users section that I just had to send out to a user.

Comment: Looks like that section is locked out until the app has been published too. I got this error when trying to upload it there: "Upload failed
The app com.[appname] needs to be published before you can use internal app sharing." When did you last use that feature? It seems like they change things around fairly often so they may have removed that functionality I'm thinking?

Comment: An app doesn't have to be published to the production track before you can publish to the internal track.  But yes, you have to publish to the internal track before you can get an Opt-In testing URL, that's because publishing actually puts the build up on an internal test track server with a URL.  The difference is that an app published to the internal test track is not visible to the general public on the App Store, but will be visible to anyone logged in to Google Play with an e-mail address registered as an Opt-In.  I did this in late September.

Comment: Looks like it went through, and yes I searched it on the google play store and saw it had a proper store entry even for just the internal test track. It spooked me before I verified it was not visible to others heh